# How prove this $4A^5+2A^3+A=7I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_{n\times n}$ is Hermitian matrix,and $A_{n\times n}\neq I_{n\times n}$,where $I_{n\times n}$ is Identity matrix,

prove or disprove

$$4A^5+2A^3+A=7I$$

my try: if such this condition: then matrix $A$ Characteristic polynomial 
$$4\lambda^5+2\lambda^3+\lambda=7$$
$$(\lambda-1)(4\lambda^4+4\lambda^3+4\lambda^2+4\lambda+7)=0$$

then I can't

since  Hermitian matrix :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix

Comment: Check the problem carefully. This is not it.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be true for *any* matrix $A$. Just take $A=0$.

Also, this can't be true for any matrix since its eigenvalues must be subset of the  roots of
$$
4 x^5+2x^3+x=7
$$
and the above equation has only one real root $x=1$. So the only possibility is $A = I$ since $(x-1)$ has to be the minimal polynomial.